# How to assemble Cassandra Connector for Spark for Scala 2.11?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

Can somebody tell me how to build the Spark-Cassandra Connector assembly?  I've tried following the instructions on the Github page https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector but I just get hundreds of "deduplicate" errors.

I'm using Scala 2.11.7 with Spark 1.5.1 (which I built for Scala 2.11) and SBT 13.8.

I did the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector.git
cd spark-cassandra-connector/
sbt -Dscala-2.11=true assembly
```

The build process runs for a while, but then starts spitting out hundreds of "deduplicate" errors and fails.  I have no idea where to start fixing this, but right now as far as I can tell the assembly build process for this project just doesn't work.

Any tips on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the build for 2.11 is broken and you should report it to the project. Dunno how to fix it right now.

```
➜  spark-cassandra-connector git:(master) sbt
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/dev/oss/spark-cassandra-connector/project
Using releases: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2 for releases
Using snapshots: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots for snapshots

  Scala: 2.10.5 [To build against Scala 2.11 use '-Dscala-2.11=true']
  Scala Binary: 2.10
  Java: target=1.7 user=1.8.0_66

[info] Set current project to root (in build file:/Users/jacek/dev/oss/spark-cassandra-connector/)
[root]> update
...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Done updating.
[success] Total time: 314 s, completed Dec 2, 2015 10:26:01 AM
[root]> 

➜  spark-cassandra-connector git:(master) sbt -Dscala-2.11=true
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/dev/oss/spark-cassandra-connector/project
Using releases: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2 for releases
Using snapshots: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots for snapshots

  Scala: 2.11.7
  Scala Binary: 2.11
  Java: target=1.7 user=1.8.0_66

[info] Set current project to root (in build file:/Users/jacek/dev/oss/spark-cassandra-connector/)
[root]> update
...
[error] impossible to get artifacts when data has not been loaded. IvyNode = org.slf4j#slf4j-log4j12;1.7.6
...
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last spark-cassandra-connector-embedded/*:update for the full output.
[error] (spark-cassandra-connector-embedded/*:update) java.lang.IllegalStateException: impossible to get artifacts when data has not been loaded. IvyNode = org.slf4j#slf4j-log4j12;1.7.6
[error] Total time: 9 s, completed Dec 2, 2015 10:27:19 AM
```

I filed an issue https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKC-295.

Comment: I thik you're right, Jacek.  There's a JIRA bug that sounds similar:  https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKC-249  But it's only been fixed in Spark 1.5.0, not 1.5.1.  I'll try 1.5.0 and see if it works.

Comment: Don't think so. We don't touch Spark yet. I'm reporting an issue.

Comment: OK - thanks.  I'm hitting several problems around Spark and Scala versions - you have to build Spark manually for Scala 2.11, you have to build the Spark-Connector assembly manually, and so on.  I'm thinking it might be easier to drop back to older versions of Scala/Spark etc, to eliminate some of these manual steps, even if it means having to wait before we can use some of the cool new features.